# Why is my python class inheritance incorrect?

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm learning to use PyQt5 and have run across a problem. My code is attempting to just draw a simple black box in the `QMainWindow` object by writing a second class `PaintWidget` which inherits from `QWidget`. I've posted my code first, and the correct one below it.

```
class PaintWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.qp = QPainter()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.qp.fillRect(1,1,100,100, Qt.black)
```

Correct:

```
class PaintWidget(QWidget):
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.fillRect(1, 1, 100, 100, Qt.black)
```

This is what confuses me. In order to create this class, we need to inherint from the super class `QWidget`, inorder to do so we use the function `super().__init__()` under `__init__(self)`. We then set up the `QPaint` object which we will use in our method `initUI()` which actually does the work. Now this doesn't work when I run it.

The second, correct class, doesn't even seem to inherent, since it has no `super().__init__()`, even worse, it is setting up a method that is never even called (`paintevent(self, event)`), which takes an argument that seemingly comes from nowhere. Can someone point out why I'm wrong?

Comment: `paintEvent` is called by PyQt5 with an argument it provides, and if you don’t override `__init__`, it defaults to the parent class’s, put simply.

Comment: So setting up a new `__init__` is not needed? The reason I wanted to make one is that I thought it would make passing extra parameters to it easier, such as if I waned to change to color of the rectangle, it'd be easier to call `painter = PaintWidget(Qt.yellow)`.

Comment: @Astrum, no `__init__` is only needed if you want to initialize anything in it. Otherwise, the runtime will simply call the parent (`super().__init__()`) directly. However, if you want constructor parameters, go ahead and add it. It is not a problem either way. The difference is where you call the painter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference to *inheritance* between the two cases. In both cases you say `class PaintWidget(QWidget)`, so you are inheriting the `QWidget`.

The difference is in where you draw. In constructor (`__init__`), the widget is not yet mapped to the screen, so if you try to draw there, it won't have effect.

When the widget is actually displayed on screen, the system will invoke the `paintEvent`, which is a virtual method of the `QWidget`, and that is where you must draw the content. You only define that method in the second example.

Note that *you need fresh `QPainter` in each invocation of the `paintEvent`*. Creating one in the constructor and then using it in `paintEvent` would *not work*.

Also, most windowing systems *don't remember* the content of the widget when it is not actually visible on screen and rely on being able to call the `paintEvent` whenever the widget becomes visible again. So the method will likely be called many times. In contrast, the constructor, `__init__`, is only called once when creating the object.

Comment: So that kind of makes sense. I still have a question. Why do we have to call this class by doing `self.painter = PaintWidget(self)`? Usually when I've had to call classes, the `self` is left out.

Comment: @Astrum, `QWidget` wants the *parent widget* as argument. Which also means the `__init__` should actually be `def __init__(self, parent): super().__init__(parent)` … (plus any other parameters you want your class.

Comment: Ok, so this may be offtopic, but *why* is it different from the usual classes? This is the first time I've come across this type of thing before and it seems odd. If the class has already inherited the parent, it seems odd to have to be explicit about it.

Comment: @Astrum, this is not different from other classes. The *parent* does *not* mean the class it inherits—that is a “base”. The *parent* is the widget on which your widget will appear on screen.